# JSONP call successful, but getting Error: JSONP injected script did not invoke callback

Tags: angular, jsonp, angular7

I am trying to make a JSONP call to the following API: https://api.openrates.io/latest

My service code:

```
this.http
    .jsonp<Response>("http://api.openrates.io/latest", "callback")
    .subscribe(res => console.warn(res));
```

From the DevTools Network Tab I can see that the request was successful and I am getting a JSON object back:

[image]

However I get the following exception and I cannot subscribe to the response properly:

[image]

Is it a problem in the way I make the JSONP call? Or is the server answer the issue (JSON and not a callback)?
For sake of completeness I use Angular 7 and Angular CLI.

Comment: From the official website - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#head the second parameter to jsonp is a object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Issue is with response type. Its pretty pure json type however `jsonp` format should looks like -

```
/**/ng_jsonp_callback_7({,…});
has_more: false
items: [{new_active_users: 9, total_users: 9580180, badges_per_minute: 5.37, total_badges: 28924187,…}]
quota_max: 300
quota_remaining: 298
```

> So instead of using `jsonp` you can use `get` method.

working copy is here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-http-jsonp-yd9z1r

Comment: Even without any API parameters it fails: "Http failure response for http://api.openrates.io/latest?callback=ng_jsonp_callback_0: 0 JSONP Error". If you refer to the jsonp call, it accepts 2 parameters and the "callback" parameter is in this case mandatory.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: The response format of `jsonp` is wrong. See the updated answer.

Comment: Indeed the response was not in JSONP format, but in plain JSON. When I initially used "HTTP" I got the before mentioned CORS error, due to "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" (+1 for that!) as you said. Now withjust a GET + Https it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be, you should try calling .map with pipeable operator.

```
return this.http
    .jsonp<Response>("http://api.openrates.io/latest", "callback").pipe(
       map(res=>res),
       tap(res=>console.log(res))
    );
```

Also check JSON response is valid.

Comment: no, map does not solve the issue. the observer is not subscribed due to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily, if you just need to test your API endpoints locally, you can just run a new session of Chrome where web security is disabled.

You can hit Window + R then execute this script.

```
chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```